# Accessing registered Django MIDDLEWARE object

Tags: django

I have defined a middleware class `XYZMiddleware` and have registered it in `settings.MIDDLEWARE`.

`XYZMiddleware` objects have relevant state, so in my integration test I need to access the `XYZMiddleware` object that Django (as of 1.11) has created.

How do I retrieve it? 
(The docs do not appear to talk about it, neither the [topic docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware) nor the [reference docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware).)

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is loaded and registered in `BaseHandler.load_middleware` (in `django.core.handlers.base`). That code does not look like it means to make the middleware objects accessible.

Looking again at the middleware docs, 
I found the following [remark about `__init__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#init-get-response):

> Unlike the `__call__()` method which is called once per request,
>   `__init__()` is called only *once*, when the Web server starts.

Emphasis in the original.
That sounds to me as if only one instance of the middleware class will exist. So the right solution should be to turn the state
from instance variables into class variables.